# ¿Cómo instalar genymotion en ubuntu/linux mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

Cuando instalo genymotion en linux mint, arranca el emulador y se cierra enseguida.

¿Qué debo hacer para instalarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para instalar genymotion exitosamente en ubuntu/linuxmint es necesario instalar el driver privativo de la tarjeta de video.

Por ejemplo, en mi caso, la tarjeta de video es NVIDIA GT218 [GeForce 210] y solo basta con instalar el driver de esta forma:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-340

# Advertencia: instale el paquete debajo de la línea para kernels >= 5.11

sudo apt install xorg-modulepath-fix
```

y listo: con esto funcionará genymotion.

Comment: No olvides traducir el comentario presente entre los comandos, ya que es información muy relevante. Tampoco olvides [aceptar](help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.